# How can I add locale changer in Rails Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, rails-i18n

I am using rails admin and I need to add language(locale, I18n) changer to a header or a dashboard. May be there is standard feature how to change locale in rails_admin? If not how can I just add a link somewhere (dashboard or header)?